# Obtain Event Object in Function With Parameters

Tags: javascript

So I'm adding a keydown listener on my page when you are focused on a certain element, but I want to remove it when you are not on this element. This works fine, but I can't find a way to pass the event object (needed for `e.preventDefault()`) into this function. The following is a relevant snippet of my code:

```
// Named function for keydown listener (I need to pass the line 
// and layer objects into the function)
function keydownListener(line, layer) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... using the line and layer for various things ...
}

// adds event listener when you click on specific element
some_element.addEventListener('click', function() {(
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keydownListener(line, layer));
});

// removes event listener when you click on anywhere else (not real code. just to 
// demonstrate the idea)
anything_else.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', keydownListener);
});
```

Is there no way to pass the event object into a function with other parameters?

Comment: Also I'm aware I can fix this by making the line and layer variables into a global scope, but I'd like to avoid that. I'm also just curious as to whether or not there is a way to do this.

Comment: where are line and layer coming from?

Comment: `window.addEventListener('keydown', keydownListener(line, layer))` sets the listener to the result of calling `keydownListener(line, layer)`.

Comment: They're just objects created through Kinetic.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to pass the event to the keydownListener when click event is triggered

```
function handler(e)
    keydownListener(line, layer, e)
};

// adds event listener when you click on specific element
some_element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handler)
});


// Named function for keydown listener (I need to pass the line 
// and layer objects into the function)
function keydownListener(line, layer, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... using the line and layer for various things ...
}
```

Comment: If I use an unnamed function to do that, how will I remove the event listener?

Comment: yeah, right. Is it better know? Knowing where line and layer are coming from would be nice, though :D

Answer (score 1):

The event listener function receives the `event` as its first argument, though some browsers have this as a global variable:

```
foo.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    callOtherFunction(event, arg1, arg2);
});
```

Comment: When I do this, it says that e.preventDefault() is undefined.

Comment: Also yeah I could call another function, but how would I pass it into an event listener without requiring an unnamed function? I can't use an unnamed function because then I can not remove that specific event listener.

Comment: You don't need to use an unnamed function. Functions are first class citizens in JavaScript. You can pass them around just like any other variable: `foo.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);`